# Python swap function is not working using index method with list=[1,2,3]

Tags: python, list, swap

I am trying to swap elements using python list index method which would return index of an element.
So that I Can swap as like as I need using know elements.

Here's the code...

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]


a[a.index(1)],a[a.index(2)] = a[a.index(2)],a[a.index(1)]
```

**output**

```
>>>a
>>>[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

And again I tried to use swap elements and now here's the output

```
a = [2,1,3,4,5,6]


a[a.index(1)],a[a.index(2)] = a[a.index(2)],a[a.index(1)]
```

**output**

```
>>> a
>>> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

[image: with list [2,1,3,4,5,6]]

[image: Output with list [2,1,3,4,5,6]]

**output with list [1,2,3,4,5,6]**
[image]

Comment: Can you describe your use case? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Do you want to swap first and second values or 1 and 2 values?

Comment: for the list [1,2,3,4,5,6] its needs to be [2,1,3,4,5,6] but its giving as like as given list i.e `a` but when it's coming to list [2,1,3,4,5,6] its working fine and output is [1,2,3,4,5,6]!
Its not working only when list elements are [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: try to run with the above code... with lists [1,2,3,4,5,6] and [2,1,3,4,5,6]... and I think you guys know about my issue :(

Comment: .. and for the list `[3,4,1,5,2]` ?

Comment: output is list as you've given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of Python's [evaluation order](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) and because of the fact that you change the list **in the middle** of this evaluation:

For an assignment, first the RHS is evaluated, from left to right:

```
# a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a[a.index(2)], a[a.index(1)] =>  2, 1
```

Now, the LHS is evaluated from left to right. So, first:

```
# a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a[a.index(1)] => a[0] = 2
# now a = [2,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Notice that now the (**first**) index of `2` is `0`!!!

Next evaluation is:

```
# a = [2,2,3,4,5,6]
a[a.index(2)] => a[0] = 1
# now a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

So you end up with the same list...

---

This is also because the [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) method returns the:

> index of the **first** occurrence of *x* in *s*

---

For the second list, the RHS is evaluated the same, but then at the LHS you have:

```
# a = [2,1,3,4,5,6]
a[a.index(1)] => a[1] = 2
# now a = [2,2,3,4,5,6]
```

And now:

```
# a = [2,2,3,4,5,6]
a[a.index(2)] => a[0] = 1
# now a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

So it seems fine...